# let $f(x,y,z)= (e^{y+2z},xe^{y+2z},2xe^{y+2z})$ show that $F$ is conservative over $xyz$-plane

Tags: calculus

This function also has potential function $f(x,y,z)=x e^{y+2z}$. I need to also evaluate $\int F x dr$ over the line segment from $(1,1,2)$ to $(2,3,4)$.

Not sure how to prove something is conservative or how to move to the second step listed above. I have tried taking integrals but to no avail.

Comment: Since the problem is in $\mathbb{R}^3$ maybe you can use the fact that a field $F$, is conservative if $\nabla \times F = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

A vector field is conservative if it can be written as a potential (i.e. $F = \nabla f$ for some scalar function $f$).  The answer to your other question is the fundamental theorem of line integrals

$$
\int F\cdot ds \;\; =\;\; \int (\nabla f)\cdot ds \;\; =\;\; f |_{\text{end points}}.
$$